# jquery dialog cause other function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I have a OK button, when click it, it calls hideTyre(). the hideTyre() function calls SetBankFees function.
I also have $("#dialog-immpay").dialog()  and  $("#dialog-SelectFees").dialog().

The problem is that when I place hideTyre() before the two dialog(), OK button click cannot found the hideTyre(),
if I place the hideTyre() after the two dialog(), then hideTyre() is executed, but I got another error, it says the SetBankFees() is undefined.

Although the two dialog() work fine here, I guess the two dialog() cause the problem. But I could not figure out whats wrong there.

I appreciate your help very much.

```
<script>
       ...more js functions

        function  SetBankFees()
       {

`enter code here`       }

`enter code here`        ...more js functions

       function hideTyre()
        {
           SetBankFees();
            $("#tyreDiv").hide();
           $(".main").show();
        }

       var immPayF8OrF9 = "";
        $("#dialog-immpay").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 400,
            width: 750,
          modal: true,
            dialogClass: "no-close",
            buttons: {
                "Save without Print Invoice": function () {
                    allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");

                    FImmPay = immPay_Payment;
                  FComp = immPay_Comp;
                    FImmPayDate = CCDateStrToJDate($("#datePay").val());
                   FCompDate = CCDateStrToJDate($("#dateCom").val());
                    if ((FImmPay > 0.005) || (FComp > 0.005))
                    {
                        FSaveImmPay = true;
                       FImmPayReceipt = immPay_Receipt;
                  }
                    else
                   FSaveImmPay = false;

                   FPrtInv = immPay_PrtInv;

                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "print all unissued invoices": function () {
                    allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");

                    FImmPay = immPay_Payment;
                   FComp = immPay_Comp;
                    FImmPayDate = CCDateStrToJDate($("#datePay").val());
                  FCompDate = CCDateStrToJDate($("#dateCom").val());
                  if ((FImmPay > 0.005) || (FComp > 0.005))
                   {
                      FSaveImmPay = true;
                       FImmPayReceipt = immPay_Receipt;
                    }
                    else
                       FSaveImmPay = false;

                    immPayF8OrF9 = "F8";

                   $(this).dialog("close");
               },
               "print last invoice only": function () {
                    allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");

                    FImmPay = immPay_Payment;
                   FComp = immPay_Comp;
                   FImmPayDate = CCDateStrToJDate($("#datePay").val());
                   FCompDate = CCDateStrToJDate($("#dateCom").val());
                    if ((FImmPay > 0.005) || (FComp > 0.005))
                   {
                       FSaveImmPay = true;
                       FImmPayReceipt = immPay_Receipt;
                   }
                    else
                       FSaveImmPay = false;

                    immPayF8OrF9 = "F9";

                 $(this).dialog("close");
              },

              "Esc": function () {
                   $(this).dialog("close");
              }
           },
            close: function() {
               allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

                if (immPayF8OrF9 == "")
                    DoAfterDoImmPay();
              else
                    ShowOption("#dialog-showPrintingOption", OriInvOption);
            }
        });

        $("#dialog-SelectFees").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 400,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Select the fee" : function () {
                    allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    AddRow(y);
                },
                "Cancel" : function(){
                    allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

    });

// if leave hideTyre() here, then error SetBankFees(); is undefined
//        function hideTyre()
//        {
//            SetBankFees();
//            $("#tyreDiv").hide();
//            $(".main").show();
//        }

    ...more js functions
</script>

<button onclick="hideTyre()">OK</button>
```

Comment: Please can you create any demo of your code?
So I can understand easily.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is function hideTyre() and function  SetBankFees() are in different scopes.

SetBankFees() is inside $(function () {}), but hideTyre() is not.
What my findings are the function outside $(function () {}) cannot access the function inside $(function () {}), but function inside $(function () {}) can access the function outside $(function () {}).